# Using shell script to grab data from Heroku Postgres database

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I'm a newbie at this. I want to write a script that I can execute from command line to run a query on a Heroku-hosted PostgreSQL database.

Right I have a script `script.sh` with executable permissions that looks like:

```
echo "Starting pull from postgres ..."
heroku pg:psql <db> --app <app-name>
\copy (<query>) to 'file.csv' WITH CSV
\q
echo "Done!"
```

The `echo` and `heroku ...` commands runs fine, however, once Heroku launches, the script no longer injects the commands. Only after I manually close out the Heroku app does it inject the last three lines.

I understand that this is a bash script that isn't intended to input postgreSQL commands once Heroku is open, but is there a way to do this?

I get the sense that it might involve connecting to Heroku and submitting the query in one line -- I searched around [Heroku's documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-heroku-postgres-databases-from-outside-of-heroku) but didn't see anything that would be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `--command` flag to pass SQL commands to `heroku pg:psql` along with the server-based [`COPY`](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/COPY) and then redirect the output to a file:

```
echo "Starting pull from postgres ..."
heroku pg:psql <db> --app <app-name> --command "COPY (<query>) TO STDOUT WITH CSV" > file.csv
echo "Done!"
```

Comment: `pg:psql` is an interactive command. It requires you to enter commands directly. The `--command` flag changes that by providing the commands upfront to be executed automatically.